# When using multiple soft asserts in multiple cucumber step definitions, cucumber extent report shows passed

Tags: java, extentreports

Suppose I have a code as follows:

```
        public class Class1 
    {
    SoftAssert softAssert=null; 
    public Class1() 
    { softAssert=new SoftAssert();
    } 
    @Given("^some feature step1$") 
    { **somecode Reporter.addStepLog("condition failed.Hence test failed"); softAssert.assertTrue(false); 
    }

    @And("^some feature step1$")
    { **somecode Reporter.addStepLog("condition failed.Hence test failed"); softAssert.assertTrue(false); 
    } @After() {
    softAssert.AssertAll(); 
    }

    }
```

When I execute the above code, it shows that the scenario has failed in test NG. but, in the Cucumber extent report, all the steps are passed (Although error messages are only displayed)

Answer (score 0):

In case of **Soft Assertion Failure**, We handle the exception because of that Test Case does not get marked as Failed. Same is passed to the Extent Report and Let's say below is the extent code in Hooks and Here control would pass over to else Statement.

```
@AfterTest
    public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
        String videoFile= Utility.stopAUTTestRecorder();
        try{
            if(scenario.isFailed()){
                //byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)DriverManager.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                //scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
                ExtentTestManager.addScreenShotsOnFailure();
                //------------------------- Attaching video in the Report -------------------------
                String failedTestVideo = "<a href=\"" + videoFile + "\">Download Failed Test Case Video</a>";
                ExtentTestManager.embedVideoLink(failedTestVideo);
                //scenario.write(failedTestVideo);
                log.info("***** Scenario Execution is - "+ scenario.getStatus().firstLetterCapitalizedName() + " (Completed) : at " + Utility.getCurrentTime() +" *****");
                BaseSteps.getInstance().quit();
            }else {
                if(ExtentTestManager.getTest().getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("pass")) {
                    ExtentTestManager.scenarioPass();
                    log.info("***** Scenario Execution is - "+ scenario.getStatus().firstLetterCapitalizedName() + " (Completed) : at " + Utility.getCurrentTime() +" *****");
                    BaseSteps.getInstance().quit();
                }else if (ExtentTestManager.getTest().getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("warning")){
                    ExtentTestManager.scenarioWarning();
                    log.info("***** Scenario Execution is - "+ scenario.getStatus().firstLetterCapitalizedName() + " (Completed) : at " + Utility.getCurrentTime() +" *****");
                    BaseSteps.getInstance().quit();
                }
            }
```

**Solution** - We would need to explicitly call the Extent Report : Fail Method () and fail it

```
// You can customize your methods as per your framework requirement - 
ExtentTestManager.logFailed("Some message");
```